# How to view different data depending on the value for SQL

Tags: sql

How can I make the values show up differently?

Example: 
I have a table '`Feelings`' with a column called '`Happy`' 
If I `select * from 'Happy'` it will bring back values `1, 2, 3` (with user IDs to show which user is which feeling)
`1` stands for Yes, `2` stands for no, `3` stands for maybe 
I want the table to not show `1,2,3` but instead show yes,no,maybe

How would I go about to making this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: by buying a book on SQL :)

Comment: `CASE ID WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN 2 THEN 'No' WHEN 3 THEN 'Maybe' END AS Name`. Maybe. Or add a name column to the table and `SELECT` that instead of the ID. Your question isn't particularly clear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. These are basic problems that any beginner ask. Below is a tutorial that I think would help you understand how SQL works. If you get stuck with a syntax error, or can't figure something out of your code, please post it here and I'll do my best to guide you in the right direction : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vtl2WggqOg

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE HAPPY
    WHEN '1' THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN '2' THEN 'No'
    WHEN '3' THEN 'Maybe'
    ELSE 'Other'
END AS 'Happy'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a table called `Feelings` and a column called `Happy` with just IDs, you can try the following query:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
      CASE HAPPY
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'No'
        WHEN '3' THEN 'Maybe'
      ELSE 'Other'
   END AS 'feeling_happy'
FROM FEELINGS
```

Otherwise, if you have 2 tables, one called `Feelings` with column `Happy` that has the IDs and another table called `Happy` with the IDs in one column and the defined statuses in another column (which we'll call `happy_x`), then you can simple use the following query:

```
SELECT
   f.user_id, h.happy_x
FROM Feelings f
  INNER JOIN Happy AS h
      ON h.id = f.happy
```

Comment: I believe she has another table that links to the users ID's. In which she wants the associated userid's based on the 1,2,3 values.  I think in the end what she needs is a simple JOIN between Feelings and Users with a WHERE clause.

Comment: There is only one else in sql this will give an error

Answer (score 0):

While you can use a CASE as other answers here you can also use a join -- to a table of lookup values or to a CTE, or VALUES clause.  Even a temp table in a stored procedure.

That would look like this:

```
SELECT user_id, COALESCE(lookup.value,'Unknown') as happy
FROM feelings
LEFT JOIN (
   VALUES 
      ('1','Yes'),
      ('2','No'),
      ('3','Maybe')
) AS lookup(k,value) ON feelings.happy = lookup.k
```

Using a join and storing related information in a table is a much more SQL way of doing things and offers many benefits including easier maintenance and often faster execution.